# Thermal Printer Driver

Tags: java, html, thermal-printer

I need to make a driver for printing .epl or .epl2 files from the browser using the Html5 or Java. I don't know what would be the correct logic to start up. How can I go through it to make a generic driver? Please help.

Similarly, I just need to print the Thermal label and supporting devices would  be thermal printers. Help required.

Comment: You don't write drivers in HTML.  That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Java is also a terrible language to write drivers in.

Comment: If not java too then? I want to understand the real concept of it? Web Based Driver to support all printers. What would be the logic behind it?

Comment: You can't "support all printers" with a single generic driver.  The whole point of drivers is that different printers speak different protocols (languages, essentially) and the driver for a specific printer knows how to communicate with that specific printer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write a printer driver, you could do that in Java, but it wouldn't involve a browser.  You'd need to know what protocol the printer speaks; if you're lucky it might understand something well-documented like PostScript or PCL, but it's likely to be something proprietary that you'd have to reverse-engineer.

But if you expect a browser to be involved, I think what you really mean is that you want to let a user view and print one of these images from a browser.  You could use HTML5 Canvas and JavaScript to read the image file and render it into the browser so the user can see it; from there, he can print it to any printer he has installed on his computer.  But JavaScript code running in a browser can't control a printer directly, so the user would need to have a driver for the thermal printer installed already.  (The manufacturer probably provides one, since the product wouldn't be much use without it.)

Comment: Okay, so you mean I need the html5 canvas and JavaScript to render out the screen. JavaScript doesn't interact with printer directly right? And, I need the thermal printer already installed? Can I make a driver to interact with that driver?

Comment: You use HTML and JavaScript to render to the screen, and the browser knows how to take what's on the screen and feed it to the system's printing API (when you choose Print from the menu).  The printing API gives the image data to the driver, which knows what bytes to send to the printer to make it print that image on paper.

Comment: Installing a driver is part of the process of setting up a printer for use in an operating system.  If the thermal printer is available as one of the choices in the Print window, the system has a driver that it will use for printing to that printer.  (It's possible that the user chose the *wrong* driver when he installed the printer, so it won't print correctly, but that's the user's problem.  It's not something your JavaScript code can control.)

Comment: Do you have example regarding it please? I mean how can I render that using javascript?